# Return multiple tables to C++, how to know the returned table name

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I am using Lua to implement some functions, results are put in table**s** and returned back to a C++ code. For example, at the end of Lua, I return these **tables** to C++

```
return names, ages, courses
```

Now in C++, I need to read elements in tables returned. How can I know the name of the table so that I know what elements to retrieve? In other words, following sudo codes illustate what I want to do:

```
if table_name == "names":  //some commands can realize this?
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Tom");
    the_name = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    cout << the_name << endl;
    Lua_pop(L, 1);
elif table_name == "ages": //similar to last comment...
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "girls");
    the_age = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    ....... //some operations
```

Anyone has any idea? BTW, I am using Lua5.3.1 on win7

Comment: You could have a field in all your tables which contains their name/type.

Comment: @malhotraprateek sounds good!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Like all Lua values, tables don't have names. Variables have names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a field in all your tables which contains their name/type.

Comment: well...seems something wrong...see here is my code;

Answer (score 1):

You won't know the variable names as which the tables were previously stored, but your Lua function returns them in specific order. In C++ these tables are put on the stack, so `courses` is the top value and `ages` the next below.